# ImportError: No module named grpc

Tags: python

when run the spec using gauge on windows system,
I get the error message below:

```
gauge\plugins\python\0.3.15\start.py", line 9, in <module>
import grpc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grpc'
Error occurred while waiting for runner process to finish.
```

Is there anyone had some ideas?

Comment: did you try `pip install grpc`?

Answer (score 2):

According to docs, upgrade your pip to version 9 or higher.
Then use the following commands:

```
$ python -m pip install grpcio
$ python -m pip install grpcio-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install grpcio
pip install grpcio-tools
```

these operations works for me